# Modifying differential equations representing a projectile system to account for an arbitrary force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, differential-equations

The following series of differential equations represents a projectile's path when solved (g=9.81):

[image: The system]

Here is some sample output from this system (with initial values x,y=0, v=1500, theta=1.33):

[image: Initial output]

I need to modify this series of differential equations to account for a force F with components a and b acting on the projectile. I have tried to duplicate gravity's effect on the projectile and then adding terms to the equations:

```
vdot = -g*sin(theta) + a*cos(theta) + b*sin(theta)
```

and

```
thetadot = -g/v*cos(theta) + a/v*sin(theta) + b/v*cos(theta)
```

But this series of differential equations does not behave properly, instead resulting in the following with a force with i-component 20 and j-component -20:

[image: Incorrect series]

Intuitively, the positive i-component should push the projectile in the forwards x-direction, but instead, it pushes it backwards, over the y-axis into a negative x.

What is the proper solution to this problem? Thanks.

**Edit: Thanks to Joshua Lin, I've gotten the direction component of the second term in thetadot worked out, however, I still am not sure if this is correct (I don't understand it geometrically). Here's output from the fixed term sign:**

[image: Attempt 2]

New thetadot:

```
thetadot = -g/v*cos(theta) - a/v*sin(theta) + b/v*cos(theta)
```

Comment: Should the second term in your thetadot expression be a negative? Not too sure but it seems in my head to be negative

Comment: As the g component is positive (it's confusing, but it was the way the problem was asked) and the first term of thetadot is negative, I assumed that because the force given assumes that a and b accurately represent the direction, those terms should be positive. If you could explain why the second term should be negative, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CrELh1k.png

both positive g and positive a forces seem to decrease the angle (hence putting a negative sign in front) whereas b seems to increase the angle (hence the justified positive sign)

Comment: Not too sure though, just pulling at straws here

Comment: What does the output with a negative in front of the second term look like?

Comment: It looks slightly more reasonable: http://i.imgur.com/BQrw8pV.png However, that doesn't mean it's correct, if you get what I'm saying.

Comment: All motions obey $\vec F = m\ddot{\vec x}$. Just coordinate transform that equation into $r,\theta$ instead of adding terms by guesswork.

Comment: From some scratchwork, it seems that a coordinate transform would require some roots involved in the vdot equation, which isn't in the preliminary "solution". Does that mean that my vdot term is incorrect?

Sorry for being dense, this just is extremely confusing for me from a trigonometric perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:  While I was typing the answer below, I see that you came to the same conclusion as I do in my answer below.

---

From your $\dot \theta$ equation, it appears that a positive $x$ component of force acts to *increase* the rate of change of the angle when $0 \lt \theta \lt \pi$.

But, that *can't* be correct.  If you set $g$ and $b$ to zero and launch the projectile with speed $v$ and positive $\theta$ and $a$, the angular rate of change $\dot \theta$ should be negative, i.e., $\theta$ should asymptotically approach zero from the initial positive value.

This is because $v_x$ will grow without bound while $v_y = v_0$

Comment: The only thing I'm confused about is why the sign of the a term isn't flipped in the vdot equation as well (from a trigonometric perspective). Could you explain that?

Comment: @ylin, I did in final sentence.  Try this:  set $g = b = \theta_0 = 0$ and you get $\dot v = a$ so, if $a$ is positive, the velocity should be *increasing* as desired.  It is often helpful to set other terms to zero in order to do a sign sanity check.